# a year on: what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

PLease, dear native English speakers, help me to understand the meaning of the expression "a year on" within the context "The reality is that, a year on, a true 4K standard is still very much a work in progress..." Thank you a lot!

Comment: It's more British English than American English.

Comment: But it's not a "Britishism" by any means.

Answer (score 5):

It is an idiom that simply means *one year later*.

In the sentence you give, it is not clear what is the start of the year's duration.  However, time has run on one year - hence *one year on*.

Answer (score 5):

A year + on

According to Merriam Webster, as an adverb, "on" also means a more advanced point in space or time; later on.

According to Longman, it means after a particular time such as Now, a year on, he is one of the most successful businessmen.

So the sentence implies "The reality is that after a year, a true 4K standard is still very much a work in progress".

Comment: A little suggestion, when you mention dictionaries, providing a link will be helpful. +1 for the references anyway! :)

Comment: http://i.word.com/idictionary/on

Comment: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on_2

Comment: He means, put the references _in your answer_!

Comment: I`m very appreciated for all your help!